# Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\Temp\test.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\Temp\test.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3.

Extra information:

I have admin privilege's, the folder is located in the servers E: drive, I am logging into SQL Server via Windows authentication, not SQL Server authentication, so it should be using my access permissions to get the file.

Comment: Check read permissions on the folder for the domain account the sql service runs as.

Comment: *You* might have permissions but clearly the Account that SQL Server is running under does not. When you access files under SQL Server it's under the service accounts permissions, not yours.

Comment: @Larnu, fyi... _If a user uses a SQL Server login, the security profile of the SQL Server process account is used. ... In contrast, if a SQL Server user logs on by using Windows Authentication, the user can read only those files that can be accessed by the user account, regardless of the security profile of the SQL Server process._ [BULK INSERT - Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#security)